# Coin Tosses and Expectations

Tags: probability

I was trying to solve the question "If you are asked to play a game where you toss a fair coin again and again until you get consecutive heads and win Re. 1 or you get consecutive tails and lose and quit, how much will you be willing to pay to play this game?"
Though I believe its quite trivial in the sense question says the game terminates with either HH or TT,I perceived the question to state that game continues till a TT is encountered, with +1 at each HH (Eg + 2 for HHH).
Can someone solve this modified version.
**"If you are asked to play a game where you toss a fair coin again and again and get +1 for each consecutive heads or you get consecutive tails and lose and quit, how much will you be willing to pay to play this game?"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be in one of two states, H or T. In H, you have probability $\frac12$ of getting $+1$ and staying in H and probability $\frac12$ of transitioning to T, so, denoting the expected value in state S by $E_S$, we have $E_H=\frac12(1+E_H)+\frac12E_T$. In state T, you have probability $\frac12$ of losing and probability $\frac12$ of transitioning to H, so $E_T=\frac12\cdot0+\frac12E_H=\frac12E_H$. Substituting for $E_T$ in the first equation yields $E_H=\frac12+\frac34E_H$, so $E_H=2$ and $E_T=1$. You have probability $\frac12$ of starting in either state after the first throw, so the value of the game to you is $\frac12(2+1)=\frac32$.

Comment: What do you exactly mean denote by expected value in state S, i.e Es? Is it the expected value of money one has at state S? If yes,shouldn't it also be a function of number of tosses already made,i.e notions like Es,n (Expected Value of money at state S | The player has made n tosses)

Comment: @Parikshit: It's the expected value of money to be gained in the future when in state $S$ (which is independent of how one got into state $S$).